# Can't ping EC2 after setting up security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, network-security-groups

[image]I've just set up an EC-2 instance, and after I added a security group that for all Ips (0.0.0.0/0) and all traffic inbound and outbound is allowed. Yet, I cannot ping its public address, and I have no idea why.

Last week, following the same procedure I was able to do it, which is making me confused.

How can I deeper troubleshot this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that the SG is attached to the EC2-Instance? Could you share a picture of the Inbound-Rules of the SG?

Comment: Hello man! This is the settings I had, the exact same copy for outbound and still couldnt manage to ping it! @MaiKaY see edit for pic

Comment: And the EC2-Instance is in a `public` subnet (maybe yout put it by accident into a `private` one)?

Comment: @MaiKay its public... This is what is driving me crazy, I did this process a few times last week with no problem, and to my understanding I've changed none of the config parameters, so I am just trying to troubleshoot it... I don't know what path to take

Comment: I am asking again because you didnt confirm it. Is your SG attached to your EC2-Instance? Could you please (re)check it in the EC2 console?

Comment: Hey again! Yes it should, as it says Security Gropus: <name of my SG> (sg-XXXXX) (active).

Answer (score 2):

Check that there is an internet gateway attached to your VPC. You have to do this via the route table. You won't be able to reach your ec2 instance if there is no internet gateway regardless of the rule in your security group.[image]

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I checked and it was added by default.

Comment: Then check the Network acl. Ensure it has your Subnets associated and has inbound and outbound that allows all traffic for rule #100

Comment: Hi again friend :). I have a total of three subnets, for each of them is linked to a Network ACL that has a rule(#100) that allows ALL type of traffic for ALL protocols and ALL ports from the source 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: This scenerio might not apply to you but if your account was only reacivated after subscription suspension or something related, then the reactivation may not have been completed by aws. In my case when it was as a result of this and as it was my test account without live servers, i had to delete it and recreated another one. If this apply to you, and you dont want to delete it, you can contact aws support. Although it took time for them to come back to me to confirm the issue was due to incmplete reactivation from their end at which point i already deleted the account and created a new one

Comment: Hello, my account is brand new, and I could do this very same procedure the last week, now I cant and I don't know why. Also, I cant contact support beacuse I'm using a free tier account, could you help me out ? THanks

Comment: For free tier, you can open account specific case which was what i use for my free account.

Answer (score 0):

Ping (ICMP) is typically disabled for newly created servers and wouldnt mean that the server is not accessible. 
More details on https://serverfault.com/questions/511738/why-cant-i-ping-my-freshly-set-up-amazon-web-service-ec2-instance

Comment: Yes I know, if you read through the comments you will see all the protocols, ports and ips are enabled.